# mozilla addon. required(sdk/tabs).attach() not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I began to develop addon for firefox and I had a problem.

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

tabs.on('ready', function (tab) {
     tab.attach({
        contentScript: "alert('azaza');",
        onMessage: function(message) {
            console.log("message");
        }
      }); 
})
```

When I try to execute this code in Firefox nightly 36 it says "TypeError: window is null", but in Nightly 32 it works fine! In last fierfox (not nightly) this code not working too.

I tried to execute this code in nightly's browser debugger console, but the same result (window is null).

I can see, that in sdk/tabs/utils.js browser.contentWindow is null. I think this is my window object, but why it is null?

Comment: You're better off using a [PageMod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) if you want to affect every page.

Comment: I'm confused - are you running this code in an add-on or in the browser toolbox tool? It will not work correctly in the browser toolbox tool. Works for me in Nightly 36 though.

Comment: This is part of my addon's code. In browser toolbox tool I can see that here throwing exception.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this issue with the following code:

```
var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');

var button = ActionButton({
    icon: self.data.url("icon-16.png"),
    id: "my-button",
    label: "my button",
    onClick: function() {
        tabs.open({
            url: self.data.url("text-entry.html")
        });
        tabs.activeTab.attach({
            contentScript: "alert('azaza');"
        });
    }
});
```

To fix this issue I had to use `onOpen` instead of using `activeTab`:

```
var button = ActionButton({
    icon: self.data.url("icon-16.png"),
    id: "my-button",
    label: "my button",
    onClick: function() {
        tabs.open({
            url: self.data.url("text-entry.html"),
            onOpen: function() {
                tabs.activeTab.attach({
                    contentScript: "alert('azaza');"
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Perhaps are you using the `attach` method when you cannot use it?